# Table does not exist - SpringBoot Flyway MySql

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, flyway

I have a springboot application with H2 and have tried out some simple api(s) that does CRUD.  Now I am trying to move the db to MySQL running in a docker instance.

I have flyway configured with init script under /resources/db.migration package. I am able to connect to database from my intellij. I am able to build and start the application.

However, upon sending a REST request to save a resource, the app throws an exception. And I see `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'task-db.customer' doesn't exist` in the application log. But after building the project, I could see the customer table created via Flyway. So the table does exist before starting the application.

I tried rebuilding/invalidating cache and restarting intellij but did not help.The only fly configuration I have used is -`flyway:locations: classpath:db/migration`. Below is the DDL in the flyway init script.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CUSTOMER` (
`CUSTOMER_ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`FIRST_NAME` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
);`
```

How can I resolve it? Where should I be looking at? Am I missing something?

Comment: are you sure there isn't an issue with case-sensitivity, i.e CUSTOMER vs `customer`?

Comment: `@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")` is in my Customer entity class

Answer (score 0):

Updated the tables to lowercase in the flyway script and entities and that worked.